# Reordering Tree Node in GWT

Tags: gwt, tree

I am using GWT 2.4. I am using **Tree** in my project. I want to move tree node up or down on Button click next to particular node. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Janki, You can try the following property of **Tree** to reorder **TreeItems** attached to it.

```
myTree.insertItem(beforeIndex, item);
```

This property inserts a child tree item at the specified index containing the specified
text, where **beforeIndex** is the index where the item will be inserted
& **itemText** is the text to be added.